# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed problem

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I get this error when I tried to migrate my foreign keys.

```
Schema::create('people', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('PersonId');
        $table->integer('PersonRole');
        $table->string('PersonName');
        $table->string('Email')->unique();
        $table->string('Password');
        $table->string('Address');
        $table->string('Gender');
        $table->date('DoB');
    });

Schema::create('flowers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('FlowerId');
        $table->string('Category');
        $table->string('FlowerName');
        $table->integer('FlowerPrice');
        $table->string('Description');
        $table->string('FlowerImage');
    });

Schema::create('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('TransactionId');
        $table->dateTime('Time');
        $table->integer('PersonId')->unsigned();
    });

 Schema::table('transactiondetails', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('FlowerId')->references('FlowerId')->on('Flowers')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('TransactionId')->references('TransactionId')->on('Transactions')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    });

Schema::table('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('PersonId')->references('PersonId')->on('People')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

I tried to change the migration order, and make sure that all the variables have the same data types.

Please help me fix this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to create a foreign key to a non-primary key, it MUST be a column that has a unique constraint on it.

So in your case if you make `FlowerId` & `PersonId`  unique, it will be allowed as MySQL rule. If you can't apply a unique constraint you're out of luck, but this really does make sense if you think about it.

If you have a perfectly good primary key, why not use that :

```
Schema::table('transactiondetails', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->foreign('FlowerId')->references('id')->on('Flowers')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
     $table->foreign('TransactionId')->references('id')->on('Transactions')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
});

Schema::table('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->foreign('PersonId')->references('id')->on('People')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

A Foreign Key is a column or a combination of columns whose values match a Primary Key in a different table.(so you are not using primary key)

```
Schema::create('people', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->integer('PersonRole');
    $table->string('PersonName');
    $table->string('Email')->unique();
    $table->string('Password');
    $table->string('Address');
    $table->string('Gender');
    $table->date('DoB');
});

Schema::create('flowers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('Category');
        $table->string('FlowerName');
        $table->integer('FlowerPrice');
        $table->string('Description');
        $table->string('FlowerImage');
    });

Schema::create('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->dateTime('Time');
        $table->foreignId('PersonId')->nullable()->references('id')->on('people')->onDelete('cascade');

    });

 Schema::table('transactiondetails', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('FlowerId')->nullable()->references('id')->on('flowers')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('TransactionId')->nullable()->references('id')->on('transactions')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't indicate that a column is a foreign key without actually define the column first. Normally you'd define it first and then specify it as a foreign key. However since version 7 you can also use `foreignId`:

```
Schema::table('transactiondetails', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->foreignId('FlowerId')->constrained('Flowers')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade'); 
     $table->foreignId('TransactionId')->constrained('Transactions')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade'); 
});

Schema::table('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->foreignId('PersonId')->constrained('People')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```